# Questions on my approach to Kolakoski sequence?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

### Kolakoski sequence

I recently got interested in the Kolakoski sequence:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolakoski_sequence

$1, 2 , 2 ,1,1, 2 ,1, 2 , 2 ,1, 2 , 2 ,1,1, 2 ,1,1, 2 , 2 ,1, 2 ,1,1, 2 ,1, 2 , 2 ,1,1, 2 ,\dots$

Notice there is a $1$ once, then a $2,2$ twice, then a $ 1,1$ twice ,etc. For every number which appears once, we write a $1$ for every number which appears twice we write $2$. And we get the same sequence again! This is a Kolakoski sequence.

### My approach

I had the following idea:

Let us algorithmic-ally replace

$1 \to   a$

$2 \to  b $
$, \to x$

(Where $a$,$b$ and $x$ are matrices). Then, let:

$$  S(a,b,x) = a\cdot x \cdot b \cdot x \cdot b \cdot x \cdot a \cdot  x \cdot a \cdot  x \cdot  b \cdot  x \cdot a \cdot x \cdot  \dots$$

We define the operator $\hat O$ to have the following properties:

$ \hat O \cdot x \cdot a  \cdot x \cdot a = b \cdot x \cdot \hat O $

$ \hat O \cdot x \cdot b  \cdot x \cdot b = b \cdot x \cdot  \hat O $

$ \hat O \cdot x \cdot a  \cdot x \cdot b =  a \cdot x \cdot \hat O  \cdot x \cdot b $

$ \hat O \cdot x \cdot b  \cdot x \cdot a =  b \cdot x \cdot \hat O \cdot x \cdot a $

where the $\det a = \det b = 0$. 
Hence, by these properties:

$$ \hat O \cdot x \cdot S = S$$

### Questions

What are some good candidates for $\hat O$, $x$, $a$ and $b$ (such that $S$ still converges?) Have people already employed this approach?

Comment: If I understand right, you are saying that replacing $11->2$ and 22->2$ (i.e. $axa \to b, bxb \to b$), the Kolakoski sequence stays the same, which is not true.

Comment: @N.S. I edited the post slightly to salvage the situation ... Hopefully it makes sense now.